# как фильтровать данные по нескольким условиям pandas

Tags: python, база-данных, pandas, dataframe

Есть данные в них есть дубликаты и ошибки. Нужно получить данные в которых для каждого `user_id`
`is_trial_period` == 1 ( это будет момент регистрации) и затем для каждой записи отдельно взятого `user_id` будут оставлены даты с момента регистрации `purchase_date` + 7 и так для каждого пользователя.

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'quantity': ['1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1'],
 'is_trial_period': [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1], 'purchase_date': ['2020-01-31',
 '2020-02-07', '2020-02-14', '2020-01-17', '2020-01-24', '2020-01-23'],
 'user_id': ['8735396', '8735396', '8735396', '8735396', '8735396',
 '8735396'] })
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Что конкретно не получается? Покажите, пожалуйста, ваш код и фрейм текстом

Comment: data = pd.DataFrame({'quantity': ['1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1'],                    
                    'is_trial_period': [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1],
                    'purchase_date': ['2020-01-31', '2020-02-07', '2020-02-14', '2020-01-17', '2020-01-24', '2020-01-23'],
                    'user_id': ['8735396', '8735396', '8735396', '8735396', '8735396', '8735396']
                           })

Comment: Не могу уже поправить сообщения. (

Comment: нажмите [Править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1460670/edit) и правьте что требуется

Comment: Не могу уже поправить сообщения. (
Вообщем представленные фрейм имеет только один `user_id` в оригинале их много, мне нужно что бы брался один user_id у этого id выбирался `is_trial_period` == 1 c самой поздней датой в колонке `purchase_date` это будем момент регистрации пользователя, далее этот user_id делился на когорты понедельно, то есть если получилась строчка

`pd.DataFrame({'quantity': ['1'],                    
                    'is_trial_period': [1],
                    'purchase_date': ['2020-01-17'],
                    'user_id': ['8735396']
                           })`

Comment: Простите я не знаю что у меня тварится с браузером, все как-то криво косо отоброжается я не могу нормально написать, но надеюсь мне смогут помочь

Comment: Вообщем мне нужно что бы получилось, что береться юзер с момента регистрации ( момент регистрации это 1 в столбце `purchase_date `  с самой ранней датой) потом у него отмечался момент продления ( каждые 7 дней ) то есть пользователь зарегистрировался 2020-01-10 ( к примеру) 
то его следующая запись была 2020-01-17 и так для каждого `user_id`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
data = pd.DataFrame(
    {'quantity': ['1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1'] * 2, 'is_trial_period': [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
     'purchase_date': ['2020-01-31', '2020-02-07', '2020-02-14', '2020-01-17', '2020-01-24',
                       '2020-01-23'] * 2,
     'user_id': ['8735396'] * 6 + ['8735400'] * 6})
data.purchase_date = data.purchase_date.astype('datetime64')


def fun(x):
    date_reg = x[x.is_trial_period.eq(1)].purchase_date.min()  # дата регистрации пользователя = 1 в is_trial_period в минимальную дату
    return x[x.purchase_date.between(date_reg,date_reg+pd.Timedelta(7,'D')) & (x.purchase_date.eq(date_reg) | x.is_trial_period.eq(0))]  # возвращаем строки с датами между датой регистрации и датой регистрации + 7 дней

data = data.sort_values('purchase_date').groupby('user_id').apply(fun)
print(data)
```

```
          quantity  is_trial_period purchase_date  user_id
user_id                                                   
8735396 3        1                1    2020-01-17  8735396
        4        1                0    2020-01-24  8735396
8735400 7        1                1    2020-02-07  8735400
        8        1                0    2020-02-14  8735400
```

Comment: Почти что все верно, только нужно что бы для каждого `user_id` была одна строка с `is_trial_period ` == 1 и от минимальной даты были интервалы в 7 дней, условна фрейм на выходе должен получится такой.

Comment: data = pd.DataFrame(
    {'quantity': ['1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1'] * 2, 'is_trial_period': [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,0, 1 ,0,0,0,0] ,
     'purchase_date': ['2020-01-14',  '2020-01-21', '2020-01-28', '2020-02-05', '2020-02-12', '2020-02-19'] * 2,
     'user_id': ['8735396'] * 6 + ['8735400'] * 6})
data.purchase_date = data.purchase_date.astype('datetime64')

Comment: Условно таблица должна получиться такая, у каждого id только один is_trial_period == 1 ( остальные должны удалиться) 
и от даты регистрации у этого же id должена быть следующая запись с датой через 7 дней, но где  is_trial_period == 0 остальные записи не должны входить у этого же id, и так по всем id во фрейме.

Comment: В таблице осталось по 2 записи либо меньше, а как сделать что бы все записи вошли по каждому id &

Comment: не понял, что значит - `все записи вошли по каждому id` - они все были в исходном фрейме. тогда просто его не надо изменять

Comment: все я справился с задачкой, добавил цикл в функцию.

Comment: def date_corr(x):
    date_reg = x[x['is_trial_period'].eq(1)]['purchase_date'].min() 
    for _ in range(10):
      date_reg +=pd.Timedelta(7,'D')
      return x[x['purchase_date'].between(date_reg,date_reg+pd.Timedelta(7,'D')) & (x['purchase_date'].eq(date_reg) | x['is_trial_period'].eq(0))]

Comment: что бы есть у пользователя бесплатный периуд был 2020-01-01, потом платный через 7 дней и если пользователь еще через 7 дней совершил покупку это тоже попало в таблицу